# Department field in AD Computer Object?

Tags: active-directory, custom-attributes

I have a Powershell script that will import a csv file containing a list of computers and their respective owners, and then perform some queries on each. I am looking for a reliable way of maintaining this list so it's up-to-date and can be exported for Powershell consumption.

One idea, is that all of our computers in AD have their own respective OUs, and I am looking to use a field (Department if there is one) that will then be populated with the IT Owner. For example, in the Computers OU, there will be child OUs: "Finance Servers"; "Marketing Servers", etc. We can't use Description as this is already used.

Any ideas as I can't see additional fields or custom fields to play around with for each computer object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use the "ManagedBy" Property, however if you prefer to look over the options for yourself you can always open up powershell and run

```
get-adcomputer -identity "SomeServerName" -properties *
```

that will show you all properties that are available on that object.